# Which value to be compared in Sql Server Client Statics

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am trying to compare the performance between 2 queries. I am running Client Statics in SSMS but I am not sure which value I should be comparing. "Client Processing Time" value is not stable to be compared, because its value changes all the time.

Which values I should compare to enhance the performance?

[image]

Comment: Actually - I'd rather advice you to look at STATISTIC IO (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx) and STATISTIC TIME and then compare the IO and and server execution time against the versions of your queries.

Comment: I agree with Allan and would add using Statistics Parser which turns the data into something much easier to read. http://statisticsparser.com

Comment: For query tuning purpose Wait time on server reply is important. Client processing time depends on bytes received from server. And for production performance use use statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the "Time Statistics/Total Execution Time" to compare the performance when changing the query.

As mentioned in comments, it's better to use STATISTIC IO.

The good thing about the Clients Statistics is, you can see more information like the volume of data transferred through network. You also can change query multiple times and run and see the difference for each change.